# Define a Map in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a class in java like this:

```
public class PlaceDetail{
    private Map<String, String> addressComponents;
    List<PlaceOpenHour> openingHours;
    private List<PlacePhoto> photos;
    private List<PlaceReview> reviews;
    private List<String> types;
    private String htmlAddress;
    private String address;
    private Location location;
    private String icon;
}
```

Now i want to to use Mongoose to defind this class as a Schema, especially the Map, how can I define a Map structure in Mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PlaceDetailSchema = new Schema({
  addressComponents:[{name:String,surname:String}],
  openingHours:[new Schema({
        openHour:String, //for example openHoure and closeHoure
        closeHour:String
        })],
  PlaceOpenHour:[new Schema({
        openHour:String,
        clsoeHour:String
        })],
  photos:[new Schema({
    url:String,
    author:String
  })],
  reviews:[new Schema({
    //...write what you want
  })],
  types:[{type:String}],
  htmlAddress:String,
  address:String,
  location:[new Schema({
    country:String,
    city:String
  })],
  icon:String
});
```